# PHP won't set session to TRUE

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to create a login system but it doesn't seem to set "Session=true". Please help I'm stuck with this for too long now.

Session starts
Checked all my code
No PHP errors
and No database Errors

Login Page:

```
if($session->is_logged_in()) {
  redirect_to("index.php");
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.

  $user_name = trim($_POST['user_name']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  // Check database to see if username/password exist.
    $found_user = User::authenticate($user_name, $password);

  if ($found_user) {
    $session->login($found_user);
    redirect_to("index.php");
  } else {
    // username/password combo was not found in the database
    $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.";
  }

} else { // Form has not been submitted.
  $user_name = "";
  $password = "";
}
```

Session Class:

```
class Session {

    private $logged_in=false;
    public $user_id;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_login();
    if($this->logged_in) {
      // actions to take right away if user is logged in
    } else {
      // actions to take right away if user is not logged in
    }
    }

  public function is_logged_in() {
    return $this->logged_in;
  }

    public function login($user) {
    // database should find user based on username/password
    if($user){
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
      $this->logged_in = true;
    }
  }

  public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($this->user_id);
    $this->logged_in = false;
  }

    private function check_login() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $this->logged_in = true;
    } else {
      unset($this->user_id);
      $this->logged_in = false;
    }
  }

}

$session = new Session();
```

index page:

```
if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php");
```

Authorize Method:

```
public static function authenticate($user_name="", $password="") {
    global $database;
    $user_name = $database->escape_value($user_name);
    $password = $database->escape_value($password);

     $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='{$user_name}' AND password ='{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you opened your `php` document with `session_start()` directly after the opening `<?php`?

Comment: I have added `session_start()` in a construct method so it starts up when it is called. I also tried adding a `session_start()` after "<?php" on the login page which then gives an error saying "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution to this.

Guess what? It wasn't my codes fault but it was my servers(WAMP 2) fault. So, I uninstalled WAMP 2 and updated to the newer version WAMP 2.5. Solved my problem and no more getting redirect to login page!

Answer (score 1):

Change your is_logged_in() function to:

```
public function is_logged_in() {
  $this->check_login();
  return $this->logged_in;
}
```

Otherwise is_logged_in() will always return false on each new request (such as redirecting between pages). By calling check_login() first, it will set the logged_in variable with the value (true or false, dependent on if $_SESSION['user_id'] is set.

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I've overlooked the line in the constructor where you already call $this->check_login();

Another thing is that the authenticate function returns an Array instead of an object. So, change the following:

```
$this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
```

To

```
$this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
```

Comment: @CD001 You are correct, I overlooked that line. I edited my answer.

Comment: after logging in now I get a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User as array.

Comment: `return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;` should return a scalar (I think - probably an (int) from the primary auto-incremented id) assuming `id` is the first column in the `users` table.

Comment: Hmm okay, could you print out the $user object and verify that the property 'id' contains a value? We need to make sure $_SESSION['user_id'] is set with a valid value.

Comment: Solved the `object as array` error. Still getting redirected to login page. could it be something wrong with my php.ini?

Comment: Yeap. there is a user_id `1` and `2`.

Comment: Actually, `User::authenticate()` could return anything thinking about it... it depends entirely on what `self::find_by_sql($sql)` returns; could be an array of scalars, an array of objects or an array of arrays. All we know for certain is that `User::authenticate()` returns the first thing in that array... not sure it's going to be possible to answer this accurately without knowing what `$found_user` actually contains :\

Comment: hmmm.. i'm not sure what you meant by not knowing `$found_user`.... `$found_user=User::authenticate($user_name, $password)`

Comment: `public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id={$id} LIMIT 1");
  return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
  }`

Comment: Just one fast debug method. If you change $user->id to true in $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = true;, can you login without any problems? Also you could try to do print_r($_SESSION); exit; directly after $session->login($found_user); Just make sure everything is set correctly in the session. What CD001 actually means is that he wants to know the exact data type/structure that $found_user contains.

Comment: Seems to get the id correctly..
`Array ( [user_id] => 1 )`